# Fetch data from moodle without login with php file

Tags: php, moodle

I am facing a issue. I have to fetch data from moodle without loggin to it. I have to create a seperate php which is not a part of moodle directory. This file will fetch course from moodle database and display it. 
Please help me to sought it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up the database credentials for moodle in the [config file](https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Configuration_file) and use them to read straight from the database with a different PDO DSN?

Answer (score 0):

The right place to start would probably be to look at using the Moodle web services (https://docs.moodle.org/en/Web_services), before you start trying to directly pull information from the Moodle database.

Comment: i read the link provided by you @Curtis Mattoon. I don't know how to use it in my external .php file to access moodle database without credentials of the database.Please help

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Moodle web services. You can see the steps to set it up by going to yourmoodleurl/admin/settings.php?section=webservicesoverview. Basically,

1. Enable web services: yourmoodleurl/admin/search.php?query=enablewebservices
2. Choose which protocol your service will use: yourmoodleurl/admin/settings.php?section=webserviceprotocols
3. Create service by going to yourmoodleurl/admin/settings.php?section=externalservices and clicking the linked text "Add", give your service a name and select the box to enable, then save.
4. Add functions to the service you just created. You probably want something like core_course_get_contents, but you can study the list of api functions at yourmoodleurl/admin/webservice/documentation.php to see which functions will get you the data you want.
5. Create a user and token that will use the service. I create a user called webservice, and make the authentication method "web services authentication", and make the user a site administrator. You may not want to do that for security reasons, and just grant the webservice:createtoken privilege along with whatever privilege is necessary to access the webservice function.
6. Execute your webservice with your external script.